# python script to check Jira status

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I need a python script that will check Jira status in particular time interval (1 minutes) and once Jira ticket status is approved it will break the loop and proceed with further step (command: terraform apply). Could you please help out with code.

Using curl to fetch the Jira status:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     https://server-url/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-1?fields=status
```

Comment: If you are doing this for Production, I suggest you go Webhooks route.
Long polling/short polling is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the following program this will resolve this issue

```
import time
import json, sys, requests, os

def getStatus():
    url = "https://server-url/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-1"
    headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic base64encodethese(username:password)"
    }
    response = requests.request(
    "GET",
    url,
    headers=headers
    )
    jsonResponse = json.loads(response.text)
    return jsonResponse["status"]

def main():
    while(getStatus != "APPROVED"):
        time.sleep(50) 
    os.system("terraform apply")
```

Comment: I would suggest to keep `?fields=status` in the URL to retrieve less data (lower overhead for Jira server to generate values for all fields if they are not needed).

Comment: Yes that can also work but considering it is a 1 request per minute it won't matter much

Answer (score 0):

Checking Jira status every single minute might be demanding for the server -mainly if there are other similar requests (on other issues' statuses) sent to the server.

Alternatively, you can discuss with Jira administrators to adjust the workflow. Once the issue is transitioned to APPROVED status, they can trigger/call terraform tasks (via webhooks). Only one call is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Jira issue statuses using Jira lib:

```
from jira import JIRA

jiraOptions = {'server' : 'https://***.jira.com/'
               }
jira = JIRA(server=jiraOptions, token_auth='<api token>') #any other available auth method can be used

for singleIssue in jira.search_issues(jql_str='project = project_code'):
    print('{}: {}'.format(singleIssue.key, singleIssue.fields.status))
```